# RSS Reader NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, rss

I have create an RSS Reader as in the following tutorial:
http://techiedreams.com/android-rss-reader-part-3-action-bar-with-animated-item/

My problem is:
when i load the list (with ListActivity.java), i sometimes get a NullPointerException, and i can see only the text in some listitems and the image in some other.

The logCat is:

```
04-07 22:01:26.900: W/System.err(22141): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-07 22:01:26.900: W/System.err(22141):    at com.td.rssreader.parser.DOMParser.parseXml(DOMParser.java:56)
04-07 22:01:26.900: W/System.err(22141):    at com.td.rssreader.ListActivity$2.run(ListActivity.java:115)
04-07 22:01:26.900: W/System.err(22141):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
04-07 22:01:26.945: D/dalvikvm(22141): GC_CONCURRENT freed 887K, 10% free 13642K/15111K, paused 2ms+13ms, total 34ms
04-07 22:01:56.425: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(22141): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
04-07 22:01:56.425: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(22141): setComposingText on inactive InputConnection
04-07 22:01:56.425: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(22141): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
04-07 22:02:03.165: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(22141): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
```

The DOMParser class line 56 is :

```
theString = nchild.item(j).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
```

and the ListActivity line 115 is:

```
        feed = tmpDOMParser.parseXml(feedLink);
```

What i have to do in order to make it work..?i really can't find my error here :(

edit:

ListActivity.java

```
public class ListActivity extends Activity {

    RSSFeed feed;
    ListView lv;
    CustomListAdapter adapter;
    String feedLink;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.feed_list);

        // set the feed link for refresh
        feedLink = new SplashActivity().RSSFEEDURL;

        // Get feed form the file
        feed = (RSSFeed) getIntent().getExtras().get("feed");

        // Initialize the variables:
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        lv.setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(true);

        // Set an Adapter to the ListView
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Set on item click listener to the ListView
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                // actions to be performed when a list item clicked
                int pos = arg2;

                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putSerializable("feed", feed);
                Intent intent = new Intent(ListActivity.this,
                        DetailActivity.class);
                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                intent.putExtra("pos", pos);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        new MenuInflater(this).inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return (super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.refresh_option:
            refreshList(item);
            return (true);

        case R.id.about_option:
            Toast.makeText(this, "RSS Reader!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return (true);

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void refreshList(final MenuItem item) {
        /* Attach a rotating ImageView to the refresh item as an ActionView */
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplication()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.action_refresh,
                null);

        Animation rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplication(),
                R.anim.refresh_rotate);
        rotation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        iv.startAnimation(rotation);

        item.setActionView(iv);

        // trigger feed refresh:
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                DOMParser tmpDOMParser = new DOMParser();
                feed = tmpDOMParser.parseXml(feedLink);

                ListActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (feed != null && feed.getItemCount() > 0) {
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            // lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                            item.getActionView().clearAnimation();
                            item.setActionView(null);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        adapter.imageLoader.clearCache();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    // List adapter class
    class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
        public ImageLoader imageLoader;

        public CustomListAdapter(ListActivity activity) {

            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            imageLoader = new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            // Set the total list item count
            return feed.getItemCount();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            // Inflate the item layout and set the views
            View listItem = convertView;
            int pos = position;
            if (listItem == null) {
                listItem = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            }

            // Initialize the views in the layout
            ImageView iv = (ImageView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.thumb);
            TextView tvTitle = (TextView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.title);
            TextView tvDate = (TextView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.date);

            // Set the views in the layout
            imageLoader.DisplayImage(feed.getItem(pos).getImage(), iv);
            tvTitle.setText(feed.getItem(pos).getTitle());
            tvDate.setText(feed.getItem(pos).getDate());

            return listItem;
        }

    }

}
```

DOMParser.java

```
public class DOMParser {

    private RSSFeed _feed = new RSSFeed();

    public RSSFeed parseXml(String xml) {

        // _feed.clearList();

        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(xml);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            // Create required instances
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

            // Parse the xml
            Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            // Get all <item> tags.
            NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");
            int length = nl.getLength();

            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                Node currentNode = nl.item(i);
                RSSItem _item = new RSSItem();

                NodeList nchild = currentNode.getChildNodes();
                int clength = nchild.getLength();

                // Get the required elements from each Item
                for (int j = 1; j < clength; j = j + 2) {

                    Node thisNode = nchild.item(j);
                    String theString = null;
                    String nodeName = thisNode.getNodeName();

                    theString = nchild.item(j).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();

                    if (theString != null) {
                        if ("title".equals(nodeName)) {
                            // Node name is equals to 'title' so set the Node
                            // value to the Title in the RSSItem.
                            _item.setTitle(theString);
                        }

                        else if ("description".equals(nodeName)) {
                            _item.setDescription(theString);

                            // Parse the html description to get the image url
                            String html = theString;
                            org.jsoup.nodes.Document docHtml = Jsoup
                                    .parse(html);
                            Elements imgEle = docHtml.select("img");
                            _item.setImage(imgEle.attr("src"));
                        }
//description
                        else if ("pubDate".equals(nodeName)) {

                            // We replace the plus and zero's in the date with
                            // empty string
                            String formatedDate = theString.replace(" +0000",
                                    "");
                            _item.setDate(formatedDate);
                        }


                        if ("link".equals(nodeName)) {
                            // Node name is equals to 'title' so set the Node
                            // value to the Title in the RSSItem.
                            _item.setLink(theString);
                        }
                    }
                }

                // add item to the list
                _feed.addItem(_item);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Return the final feed once all the Items are added to the RSSFeed
        // Object(_feed).
        return _feed;
    }

}
```

Comment: We need more coooooooode!

Comment: @Telthien I have added these two classes :) do you need something more?

Comment: Perhaps a little less, even :P That's a little hard to look through.

Comment: All my project is just a try  of the tutorial above!You can find as many details there mate:) but unfortunately the nullpointer presents only with some link.i mean that there are some rss link (As the one the developer uses in his tutorial),that works really stable..

Comment: i have added some lines from the rss file too.in the first item, i can get the title and no  image, but in the second i'm getting image and no text...i really can't imagine what's going wrong here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you are getting a `java.lang.NullPointerException` from:

```
theString = nchild.item(j).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
```

The issue is that you aren't `null` checking and just assuming everything is non `null`, so one of those calls in the line is returning `null`, and then you are trying to call another method on it. Also, you need some code organization. Here's what you have...

```
           for (int j = 1; j < clength; j = j + 2) {

                Node thisNode = nchild.item(j);
                String theString = null;
                String nodeName = thisNode.getNodeName();

                theString = nchild.item(j).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
                if (theString != null) {
                       // rest of your code
```

Add some `null` checking before trying to use your objects, like this:

```
    for (int j = 1; j < clength; j = j + 2) {

        Node thisNode = nchild.item(j);

        String theString = null;
        if (thisNode != null && thisNode.getFirstChild() != null) {
            theString = thisNode.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
        }

        if (theString != null) {
            String nodeName = thisNode.getNodeName();
            // rest of your code
```

**Note**: this will fix your immediate `NullPointerException`, you may have other mistakes and this may not fix everything (your code is still pretty assumptive), but this should solve the issue you are posting about.

Comment: thanks @Steven Byle ! That solved the nullpointer but i'm still getting no text or image..and the error getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection etc remains...

Comment: when i have no image i have no description too...:( and when i'm not getting text i cant get the link too

Comment: Right, you need to take some time to make sure your code can create partial data objects if certain data is not returned. That is more of a design decision on how you want it to behave depending on the data that comes back. The scope of the question was around the NPE, which I believe is now solved. If you still have other issues, feel free to ask another question.

Comment: thanks for your time mate!!i will ask another question right now:)

Comment: this is my new question @Steven Byle    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15867104/rss-reader-isnt-getting-some-tags